# How do I transition Mapbox legacy support for raster tilesets?

Tags: ios, api, mapbox

My iOS app was happy using mapbox with:

`https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.light/\(z)/\(x)/\(y).png?access_token=\(token`)

... until mapbox deprecated this type of API support.  : /

And now I'm having difficulty in figuring out how to use their new API in replacing this old functionality.

`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10/tiles/256/` doesn't provide me with my expected png tiles.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided any information about what is going wrong, but it seems you're on the right path.

They provide this migration guide: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/migrate-legacy-static-tiles-api/

In case this isn't obvious, your complete equivalent URL would be:

`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10/tiles/256/\(z)/\(x)/\(y)?access_token=\(token)`